# Socket.io takes time to load up, what to do while the page is connecting...?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

For a real-time forum app I'm working on currently.

It takes about 1-5 seconds for the sockets on my node.js server to connect and deliver the first payload, which is some database results from mongo.

I want to do something while this is happening, since otherwise I get some angular `{{ vars }}` action going on, which is kinda unappealing and na-so-fresh.

So, I was wondering if anyone had any recommendations.

Comment: [Upgrade to Websockets](https://medium.com/@ivanderbyl/why-you-don-t-need-socket-io-6848f1c871cd#.se0qjf3c09).

Comment: I also learned that the ng-bind directive (shiz you put in the HTML tag) is equivalent to the angular `{{ braces }}` but has the added bonus of not showing unrendered content.

Comment: @RobertHarvey have you made anything using websockets?  it looks very low level, which is nice in some ways, but might be something worth inspecting down the line for me after i have a working version of the app i'm making.

Comment: The guidance in the link I provided seems sensible.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yeah, socket.io has a lot of stuff going on, but if you have not made something using WebSockets, it looks like the incidental complexity is pretty high.  Seems like a performance upgrade for an elegance downgrade, and i'm a spoilt beeyatch and want both.

Comment: [This example chat client using Websocket](http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/websocket-example) requires less than 100 lines of Javascript.